# Mathematics ( Differential Equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A body was found dead at 3pm in a storage when the temperature was 50°F. The temperature of the body at the time of discovery was 80°F, the body temperature changed to 78°F after 20 minutes. Assuming the normal body temperature is 98.6°F, establish the time of death.

Comment: dT/dt =K(T-Tm), K>o , Tm is the room temperature and after integrating the above equation I had the general solution to be T=Ce^kt - Tm where C is the constant of the integral. So how can I proceed from here?

Comment: First off, I think it's $+T_m$ in the solution. At any rate, you use the numbers you're given in the problem to find $C, k$ and $T_m$, and then solve $T(t) = 98.6$ (assuming you're using the time of discovery as $t = 0$) to find the $t$ that the problem asks for.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use [Newton's law of cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_cooling).

$$T(t)=T_{\mathrm {env} }+[T(0)-T_{\mathrm {env} }]\ e^{-rt}.$$

Use your given data points in the text to determine the unknows $T_{0}$, $T_{\text{env}}$ and $r$. Set up the problem and come back if you have still further more detailed questions.